# Updating library in Raspberry

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, can-bus, python-can

i need your help. I got Raspberry PI 3, I'm programming in Python to get CAN messages via PiCAN duo. Program is working perfectly fine, but to get reasonable informations from the source i need to send every 100mS messages to the source. I used this:
`task = can.send_periodic('can0',msg,0.1)
task.start()`

But the program shows me error. I assumed it's because of old library Python_can-1.4.1. So I downloaded newest version of this from Pypi. When i open Manage plugins and click to Install from local file (or any other way) it show me internall error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/**init**.py", line 1705, in **call**
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/plugins/pip_gui.py", line 658, in _handle_install_file_click
    initialdir=get_workbench().get_local_cwd,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/ui_utils.py", line 1920, in askopenfilename
    return _get_dialog_provider().askopenfilename(**options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/ui_utils.py", line 1960, in askopenfilename
    args = cls._convert_common_options("Open file", **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/ui_utils.py", line 1994, in _convert_common_options
    filename = _options_to_zenity_filename(options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/ui_utils.py", line 2036, in _options_to_zenity_filename
    return options["initialdir"] + os.path.sep
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'method' and 'str'

I'tried to find answer for a very long time. I did Upgrade of PI, but nothing worked. Could you help me? Thank you for your answer

Comment: Are all the packages/libraries you're using up to date?

Comment: Yes, i did entire update/upgrade so they should be.